# using batch seperator 'GO' in dynamic sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

Here is the code below;

```
SET @QUERY = '

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
-- 
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_sp_duration_create_sp_duration_data_log]
@sp_name varchar(100),
@duration int,
@details varchar(250)
AS
BEGIN

IF @duration > 100
Begin
INSERT INTO [sp_duration_logs]
           ([sp_name]
           ,[duration]
           ,[details])
     VALUES
           (@sp_name
           ,@duration
           ,@details)
END
END

';
EXECUTE('USE ['+@DBNAME+']; '+@QUERY);
```

When I try to execute this t-sql command , I get an error:

> Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Procedure
>   sp_sp_duration_create_sp_duration_data_log, Line 16 'CREATE/ALTER
>   PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.

I think I need to use 'GO' in query , but when I use GO another error occurring. (Invalid object named 'GO' or something else).

Comment: You can't use `GO` inside a dynamic SQL statement, as `GO` is not a valid T-SQL command see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx *`GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor.`*.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @QUERY = 'SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO
```

`//your code
';`

`EXECUTE('USE ['+@DBNAME+'] GO '+@QUERY);`

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

Comment: i try that but i get an error again

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SET @QUERY = '

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_sp_duration_create_sp_duration_data_log]
@sp_name varchar(100),
@duration int,
@details varchar(250)
AS
BEGIN

        IF @duration > 100
        Begin
        INSERT INTO [sp_duration_logs]
                   ([sp_name]
                   ,[duration]
                   ,[details])
             VALUES
                   (@sp_name
                   ,@duration
                   ,@details)
        END
END ';
EXECUTE('USE ['+@DBNAME+']; '+@QUERY);
```